# Proof verification: If $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x,y \in G$, then $G$ is an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I want to prove that If $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x,y \in G$, then $G$ is an abelian group.

I know that there are two other questions about the same proof. I created this post because my proof is different and I don’t know if it is valid.

Here is my proof:

By the hypothesis, $(xy)e=(xy)^{-1}e^{-1} \implies xy = y^{-1}x^{-1}$. But also $xy = x^{-1}y^{-1}$ which implies $y^{-1}x^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1}$. Inverting both sides we get $xy=yx$. $\square$?

The final step, inverting both sides, seemed like an obvious thing to do but I’m new to Algebra and I’ve never seen that in a proof before. Thanks

Comment: Use $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$, which are true in any group

Comment: @Didier Thanks for your reply. Why is my proof not valid in any group?

Comment: I did not say that your proof isn't true in all groups, I said that the relations I gave are always true.

Comment: @Math55 which part do you think is not valid? The last deduction?

Comment: @Mikasa Yeah. I haven’t seen inverting both sides thing thing before in any proof before but it seemed really obvious to me

Comment: Your last sentence is "not valid". You should rather say: "The final step is justfied by the general rule that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ for all $a,b\in G$." Also, your proof is not "different". On the contrary, hundreds of other posts here argue like you did.

Comment: @Math55 I think and see that Dietrich said you all the story. Leading comments!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is it okay to assume that $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$ if $a=b$?

Comment: @Math55 If you are working on a group, so multiply both sides of the left by $a$ and then by $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

As mentioned in the comments, though, you need to justify the last step. Namely:

$$\begin{align}
(xy)^{-1}&=y^{-1}x^{-1}\\
&= x^{-1}y^{-1} \\
&=(yx)^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

It then follows from the fact that $(z^{-1})^{-1}=z$ for all $z\in G$, that

$$xy=yx.$$

Since $x,y$ were arbitrary, $G$ must be abelian.

---

Alternatively, for any $x\in G$, we have

$$\begin{align}
x&=xe\\
&=e^{-1}x^{-1}\\
&=ex^{-1}\\
&=x^{-1};
\end{align}$$

that is, every element has order at most two. Then $(ab)^2=e=a^2b^2$ for all $a,b\in G$, so that

$$\begin{align}
ba&=a^{-1}(abab)b^{-1}\\
&=a^{-1}(aabb)b^{-1}\\
&=ab.
\end{align}$$

But $a,b\in G$ were arbitrary. Hence $G$ is abelian.